# RegEx not working with my jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, forms, validation

Can someone help me please, I want to show an error when the user makes an invalid input with jquery.
It works if the input is null, but does not work with RegEx.

Here is the html code :

```
<div class="error" style="padding:5px 10px;background-color:yellow;border:1px solid red;border-radius:5px;display:none"></div>


  <input type="text" name="nama">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Cek">
```

And here the jQuery

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var justChar = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        $('input[name="submit"]').click(function () {
            if ($('input[name="nama"]').val() === "") {

                $('.error').html('<ol></ol>');
                if ($('input[name="nama"]').val() === "") {
                    $('.error ol').append("<li>Name Must Be Require</li>");
                } else if (!justChar.test($('input[name="nama"]').val())) {
                    $('.error ol').append("<li>Name Must Be Character</li>");
                }

                $('.error').slideDown('slow');
                return false;
            }
            return true;

        });

    });
```

i've write in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jVs6w)

Comment: if it is not empty then your inner condition check is not even made. see outer check - `if ($('input[name="nama"]').val() === "") {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parent condition `if ($('input[name="nama"]').val() === "")` as it is nonsense if you want to analyse your input value.

And for matching the regex, use the jQuery style method: `$('input[name="nama"]').val().match(justChar);`

Comment: Thanks, wow I did not see that you were first to answer. I gave you a +1 for that

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for suggesting the value-add :)

Comment: the both you mean is like this? $('input[name="submit"]').click(function () { $('input[name="nama"]').val().match(justChar); }); then where i must write the code for show the error type? @prash

Comment: No, we didn't say that. We said to replace the way you call the regex matching. see my updated answer for the demo code. Also updated for hiding the error when you actually don't have an error

Comment: what do you mean by that stupid comment? Its a tested code. You already accepted as answer though!. edited with jsfiddle link. Learn to respect and try first

Comment: oops sorry @prash, its work sorry for my bad i just missspell the code :v i owe you :D i've bad internet connection with jsfiddle. thanks for your respect :D

Comment: huhh..you truly don't deserve help, I am glad this would help someone else later.

Comment: hey @prash how to identification the `<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">` in jquery?. i've try `(input[name="gender"]).val()` its not working

Comment: Short and sweet, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex check is misplaced, it is under the condition `if ($('input[name="nama"]').val() === "")` So the regex will never be checked

I got this working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var justChar = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    $('input[name="submit"]').click(function(){    
        if($('input[name="nama"]').val() === "") {
            $('.error').html('<ol></ol>');
            $('.error ol').append("<li>Name Must Be Require</li>"); 
            $('.error').slideDown('slow');
            return false;
        } else if(!justChar.test($('input[name="nama"]').val())) {
            $('.error').html('<ol></ol>');
            $('.error ol').append("<li>Name Must Be Character</li>"); 
            $('.error').slideDown('slow'); 
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: didn't notice the way you organized it, +1

Answer (score 1):

Your inner condition is checked only if the value is empty.
If it is not empty then your inner condition check is not even made. see outer check -

```
 if ($('input[name="nama"]').val() === "") {
```

update: Also, better to use the JQuery match as @Valentin Mercier has suggested. That's a good one

Remove the above line and your errors show up properly

Edit:

Showing the modified code for more clarity to the OP

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var justChar = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    $('input[name="submit"]').click(function () {
            if ($('input[name="nama"]').val() === "") {
                $('.error').html('<ol></ol>');
                $('.error ol').append("<li>Name Must Be Require</li>");
                $('.error').slideDown('slow');
                return false;
            } else if (!$('input[name="nama"]').val().match(justChar)) {
                $('.error').html('<ol></ol>');
                $('.error ol').append("<li>Name Must Be Character</li>");
                $('.error').slideDown('slow');
                return false;
            } else {
               $('.error').hide();
               return true;
            }
    });
});
```

Edit: Sharing the jsfiddle as the OP has still no idea! . Hope it helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/PrasanthSudarsanan/tLmD7/2/